# Can I access network traffic data on a webpage from a NodeJs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, browser, websocket

My current plan is to build a chrome extension that when the webpage makes a GET request, on response I handle the data. Is there a way (preferably with NodeJs) to make a request to the URL and listen for those requests/responses?

Comment: you have to create web hook for this case.

Answer (score 0):

After a few talks with some buddies, I've decided to use a headless Chrome browser.